# Navigationbar Color confusion

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, navigationbar

Environment: Xcode 8 and iOS 10.

I am try to set navigation bar color without writing codes.
[image]

This is my main UI color when the app is launched. I plan to set the Navigation bar with the same color. However, the color is a little light when it is tested. [image]

As you can see, the color in Navigation bar is a light shade.  I set the navigation bar color in the property attribute.

How to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO try adding this line of code

Comment: So why don't you just make up for the lighter effect by setting the color a little darker than it is supposed to be?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth that's like fixing a leaky bucket by replacing it with a bigger leaky bucket. Lol!

Comment: Exactly! It is a workaround, not a solution, since I don't know much about the navigation bar, @Fogmeister (posted as comment, not an answer for that reason )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In attribute inspector, try unchecking `Translucent` property. And set `Bar Tint` property to your desired color.

[image]